# Checking database for duplicate values, no error

Tags: mysql

Hi I was hoping someone could look at my section of code to see if you can find any mistakes as I can't seem to figure it out, so the section of code is;

```
//Check if the "date" textbox has a value
if ((isset($_POST['date'])) && (isset($_POST['save'])))
    {
    //Check if there is already an entry for that date
    $query = "SELECT Date FROM `".$username."Weight` WHERE Date= " . $_POST['date'];
    $existingdate = mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error().$query);
    $results = mysql_num_rows($existingdate);
    if($results > 0)
     {
      $exists = "There is already an entry for this date. To add to this entry please select the date from the 'Weight History' section and click 'Edit'";
     }
     else 
     {
     $date = $date;
     }
   }
```

The situation is;
- A user enters the date, their weight and have the option of entering notes.
- When I log in as a user and enter this information, it enters into the database fine. 
- But, when a user goes to enter another entry, I want to first check that they havent already made an entry for that day. Therefore, the above code checks if the table already contains an entry for the specified date.

I am not receiving any errors, the form just keeps entering the values, regardless of whether there is already an entry for that date.

I would really appreciate any help thanks.

Comment: echo $query (this isn't going to go well)

Comment: i think the problem is here:`"SELECT Date FROM ".$username.Weight WHERE Date=  . $_POST['date'];` because you should not mention the table name may be...

Comment: what kind of error you getting... if you pls paste the error page..

Comment: Might be a bit late now, but if you are planning to create one table for every user in you application, you might want to reconsider your schema. Try to use one and the same table for all users and introduce a column to differentiate between them.

Comment: The tablename part is working fine, I have checked that. Im not getting an error, thats the problem. When I try enter another entry on the same date I want it to give me the $exists error above, but it doesnt it just enters it into the database anyway.

Comment: $query = "SELECT `Date` FROM `".$username."weight` WHERE Date = '$date';"; Its fixed now :)